# Comparing two numbers without comparison operators

Tags: c, comparison, comparison-operators

As part of a program that I am writing for an assignment, I need to compare two numbers. Essentially, the program computes the eccentricity of an ellipse given its two axes and it has to compare the value of the calculated eccentricity to the (given) eccentricity of the Moon's orbit around the Earth, and Earth's orbit around the Sun. If the calculated eccentricity is greater than the given eccentricity, then this needs to be represented by a value of `1`, otherwise, a value of `0`. All of these values are floating-point, specifically, `long double`.

The constraints of the assignment do not allow me to use comparison operators (like `>`) or any sort of logic (`!x` or `if-else`). However, I am allowed to use the `pow` and `sqrt` functions from the `math.h` library. I am also allowed to use arithmetic operations as well as the modulo operation.

I know that I can take advantage of integer division to truncate the decimal if the denominator is greater than the numerator, *i.e.*:

`int x = eccentricity / MOON_ORBIT_ECCENTRICITY;`

... will be `0` if `MOON_ORBIT_ECCENTRICITY` is greater than `eccentricity`. However, if this relationship is inverted, then the value of `x` could be any non-zero integer. In such a case, the desired result is `1`.

The first and most intuitive (and naïve) solution was:

`int y = (x / x);`

This will return `1` if `x` is non-zero. However, if `x` is `0`, then my program crashes due to division by zero. In fact, I keep running into the problem of dividing by zero. This also happens in the case of:

`int y = (x + 1) % x;`

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this? This *seems* so frustratingly easy.

Comment: Have you checked the ceiling and floor functions?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use control statements like `if` how shall you use the result of comparison?

Comment: Can you use bitwise operations?

Comment: To generate a -1, 0, or 1 (less, equal, greater) comparing two numbers, you can use `(a-b)/fabs(a-b)`.

Comment: As a hint, you can use `pow` to avoid the `0` value. *I.e.*, manipulate `pow(2, x)` and `power(2, y)` or `pow(2, x-y)` and `pow(2, fabs(x-y))`. This will significantly reduce the maximum value of `x` or `y` you can use (from max double down to log2 of max double), but should get you there. I found a solution, but since this is your assignment... :)

Answer (score 0):

[@lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/lurker) comment above is a good approach to handle [eccentricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)) as restricted by OP.
So as not to copy that, consider the not-so-serious following:

---

```
// Return e1 > e2
int Eccentricity_Compare(long double e1, long double e2) {
  char buf[20];
  // print a number beginning with 
  //  if e2 >= e1: `+`
  //  else `-`
  sprintf(buf, "%+Le", e2 - e1);  // reverse subtraction for = case
  const char *pm = "+-";
  char *p = strchr(pm, buf[0]);
  return (int) (p - pm);
}
```

Wink, wink: OP said nothing about `<stdio.h>` functions.